# Picking models to explain between-group and over time variation of panel data

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

I have a four-period panel dataset with quite a few variables in country aggregates. I am trying to answer two questions:

Firstly, I need to identify variables which do the most to explain variation between countries. My plan here was:

1. Run a cross sectional study on one period
2. Run a pooled OLS on all periods with time dummies with clustered stderrs
3. Run a random effects model on all periods with time dummys

I don't feel like a fixed effects model would be appropriate here, because it would eliminate all the time-invariant components which likely hold a lot of explanatory power for country variation

Secondly, I need to identify the most important variables which caused an increase in the dependent variable over the 4 periods. This seems like an obvious application for a fixed effects model, which will focus on the within country variations over time. However, I am not sure if I should include time dummies in this fixed effect model. And are there other specifications I should try?

Am I on the right track?